# Install Light Table editor on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, installation, lighttable

I am trying to download/install Light Table. I want it to show up in the start menu.

When downloading light table, it shows up as a Zip folder in the TEMP file. I've extracted the files and am unable to get it to show up in the start menu.

Normally the programs I download have an installer that does this automatically. Light Table doesn't seem to have this.

I'm sure I can use it from the TEMP folder, but would really like it in the start menu, program files folder or C drive.

I've only done basic use of PCs (gaming, web browsing, MS Office).

Comment: See Windows [manual install instructions](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable).

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to do.

1. Unzip to where ever
2. Move the LightTable directory (from inside LightTableWin) to your Program Files (x86) directory.

   2.1 If you are using Windows Explorer, you'll need to start windows explorer as an administrator (found by right clicking the program icon)
3. open your Program Files (x86)\LightTable directory, right click
   and drap the LightTable.exe file into the same directory and select
   Create Shortcut
4. Left Click your short cut and drag it to
   your start menu.  When it asks if you want to pin it to your start
   menu, select yes.
5. Click on Start, and then click on the light table short cut.
6. Use Light Table